# Ionic pull to refresh locks entire page while refreshing

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, ionic-native, pull-to-refresh

I am building an app using ReactJS and Ionic v6.

On a page I've made a "pull to refresh", it works well but the issue I am facing is that while it is refreshing, my entire page scroll is locked...

I can't navigate (scroll) through my page **while refreshing**

Here's how implemented the pull to refresh :

```
 <IonPage>
      <IonContent>
        <IonRefresher
          slot="fixed"
          onIonRefresh={handleRefresh}
          pullFactor={0.5}
          pullMin={40}
        >
          <IonRefresherContent
            pullingIcon="arrow-down-outline"
            pullingText="Tirer pour actualiser..."
            refreshingSpinner="crescent"
          ></IonRefresherContent>
        </IonRefresher>
 
        <main className="content">
         ...
        </main>
      <IonContent/>
<IonPage/>
```

Is there a way to make the pull to refresh "non-blocking" ?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: No, there isn't. The whole point to refresh is changing content. Sounds like what you want is "infinite scroll"

Comment: I wanted to make a pull to refresh as in iOS Mail or Outlook app... you can tigger refresh by pulling but still can interact with the app while refreshing (when loading is finished, the spinner just disappears and data updates but nothing "locks" the app...